# Set network interface on client host to be used for Cache connections

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I'm connecting to Intersystems Cache database using Intersystems JDBC Driver. There are several network interfaces on client host. I need to make all the Cache traffic to go through a particular interface.
Is there a way to choose which network interface to use for Cache connection via JDBC Driver API or somehow via Java code? The approach to use `ip route add` is suitable but I'm looking for a Java-way like `setLocalAddress()` on some APIs or something.

Comment: Unlikely, because Java itself doesn't offer you a way to control this. It relies on the lower level routing provided by the OS, except maybe if the JDBC driver provides a way to specify a custom socket factory so you can specify the local address.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel! Thanks for your comment. Yep, that's what I was worried about - I didn't find anything straightforward in api :(